# How to fill missing dates and values in partitioned data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

How to fill missing dates and values in partitioned data?

I'm having a lot of trouble Googling this as most of the posts seem to feature Oracle databases, and I'm working with Microsoft SQL Server.

I have the following hypothetical table:

```
name       date          val
-------------------------------
A          01/01/2014     1.5
A          01/03/2014     2
A          01/06/2014     5
B          01/02/2014     90
B          01/07/2014     10
```

I want to fill in the dates in between the gaps and copy over the value from the most recent following date.  In addition, I would like to fill in dates that 1) go back to a pre-set MINDATE (let's say it's 12/29/2013) and 2) go up to the current date (let's say it's 01/09/2014) - and for 2) the default values will be 1.

So, the output would be:

```
name       date          val
-------------------------------
A          12/29/2014     1.5
A          12/30/2014     1.5
A          12/31/2014     1.5
A          01/01/2014     1.5   <- original
A          01/02/2014     2
A          01/03/2014     2     <- original
A          01/04/2014     5
A          01/05/2014     5
A          01/06/2014     5     <- original
A          01/07/2014     1
A          01/08/2014     1
A          01/09/2014     1
B          12/29/2014     90
B          12/30/2014     90
B          12/31/2014     90
B          01/01/2014     90
B          01/02/2014     90    <- original
B          01/03/2014     10
B          01/04/2014     10
B          01/05/2014     10
B          01/06/2014     10
B          01/07/2014     10    <- original
B          01/08/2014     1
B          01/09/2014     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to generate the dates.  Then you can generate all the combinations of date and name.  Finally, fill in the values.  Here is an example using `cross apply`:

```
with dates as (
      select @MINDATE as thedate
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, thedate)
      from dates
      where dateadd(day, 1, thedate) <= getdate()
     )
select thedate, vals.val
from dates cross join
     (select distinct name from hypothetical) h cross apply
     (select top 1 val
      from hypothetical h2
      where h2.name = h.name and h2.date <= dates.thedate
      order by date desc
     ) vals;
```

Comment: What do you have a `cross apply` with a table definition instead of a function? Shouldn't it be a `cross join`?

Comment: @Gabe . . . `apply` can be used either with subqueries or functions.  In this case, you'll notice that the query is really a correlated subquery and `apply` is how you can include these in the `from` clause.

Comment: @Gordon:  Thanks for the query!  I have an additional related question:  After running the select query, I tried joining it with another table (let's call it table B), but it's going awfully slow.  Table B is organized using primary keys (name, date) with other columns containing various values.  I noticed that the select query returns rows where it's primarily sorted by "thedate" in an ascending order.  So, I suspect it's an issue where the ordering of both tables aren't aligned well?  Is it possible to remedy this?

Comment: @nwly . . . You should ask another question, including the format of the `B` table and the query that you are using.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work with BigQuery? BQ doesnt have cross apply.

Comment: @Nissan . . . I would suggest that you ask a question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66983100/how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-bigquery