# fill in times points and values in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

My data is a table that looks like this:

```
timestap        sensor1 sensor2   
1/1/2015 6:00   1       20
1/1/2015 7:00   1       20 
1/1/2015 8:00   2       20 
1/1/2015 9:00   2       21
```

To save space in db I only save values when they change so my db will look like:

```
1/1/2015 6:00   1       20
1/1/2015 8:00   2        
1/1/2015 9:00           21
```

Notice that the 1/1/2015 7:00 timestamp isn't being saved to the db and I only save the sensor values when they change.

I save the timestep (1hour in this data) in another table so I know the interval.

Is there a way to get postgres to return sensor values like the original data?
For example sensor1 = [1, 1, 2, 2] and sensor2=[20, 20, 20, 21]

Also if there is a better way to model the data, I'm open for it.

The sql looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE "sensorval" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "Value" double precision NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE "datapoint" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "Taken_datetime" timestamp with time zone,
)

CREATE TABLE "datapointsensorvalrel" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "datapoint_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "datapoint" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "sensorVal_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "sensorval" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)

CREATE INDEX "datapointsensorvalrel_datapoint_id" ON "datapointsensorvalrel" ("datapoint_id");
CREATE INDEX "datapointsensorvalrel_sensorVal_id" ON "datapointsensorvalrel" ("sensorVal_id");
```

I found this: [How to fill missing dates and values in partitioned data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750336/how-to-fill-missing-dates-and-values-in-partitioned-data) but they are trying to fill in the data in the db while I'm trying to avoid wasting space in the db.

**Update:**
Space in the db isn't the biggest issue with the data size.  The data is over sampled.  When I try to import the data, the extra data points causes the import to run too slow.  To speed this up, I'm only saving the data that changes.  After reading this [How to fill missing dates and values in partitioned data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750336/how-to-fill-missing-dates-and-values-in-partitioned-data) it may be worth back filling the missing points after the import.  I was hoping Postgres had a easy way to pull out the original data list.  I'm pulling the data out to do processing on it.

Comment: How much data do you expect to save? Is it really worth it given how it complicates querying?

Comment: If it's really this repetitive and this important to save space consider using a column store.

Comment: @jpw see the update I posted above.  If I can't find a simple way in Postgres to get the data out, I'll eat the extra hard drive space.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient solution would store only information when something changes:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_data (
  sensor integer NOT NULL, -- REFERENCES _my_sensors, to store specific sensor data
  taken  timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  value  float8 NOT NULL,
  nm     varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sensor, taken)
);
```

The data then looks like:

```
sensor |        taken        | value |             nm
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   | 2015-01-01 06:00:00 |  3.14 | Some name for the measurement
   2   | 2015-01-01 06:00:00 | 17.87 | xxx
   1   | 2015-01-01 08:00:00 |  3.56 | Sensor 1 changed value
   2   | 2015-01-01 09:00:00 | 19.23 | Sensor 2 on the move
```

This approach puts everything in a single table and you therefore do not need to store all the PK's and FK's. I did add `(sensor, taken)` as PK because that is a  sensible index to have anyway to facilitate queries.

If I am not mistaken, this obviates the need to recreate the "original data". It also scales to more sensors without any effort (such as adding columns).  And, final benefit, queries will be much easier to construct and likely be faster.