# fill missing data Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Trust me I've tried my luck finding for this problem. I've had MYSQL & SQLServer solutions and not Oracle and not to specific roll-up I require. 
Since Cross Apply is not available in the version of Oracle I'm using, I hit a road block.

Problem is simple for many of you.

Start of the universe for me is rolling 13 months.

I've a table which has

```
CREATE TABLE TBLTESTAUM (
ORDER_NO NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
RECORD_DATE DATE,
Order_SEQUENCE NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
CLASS NUMBER(3,0));

INSERT INTO TBLTESTAUM VALUES (1234, '29-Aug-2015', 34, 459);
INSERT INTO TBLTESTAUM VALUES (1234, '20-Jun-2016', 35, 877);
INSERT INTO TBLTESTAUM VALUES (1234, '20-Jun-2016', 37, 877);
INSERT INTO TBLTESTAUM VALUES (1234, '02-Jul-2016', 39, 122);
INSERT INTO TBLTESTAUM VALUES (1234, '28-Jul-2016', 40, 122);
INSERT INTO TBLTESTAUM VALUES (1234, '31-Jul-2016', 41, 311);
INSERT INTO TBLTESTAUM VALUES (1234, '10-Aug-2016', 42, 311);
INSERT INTO TBLTESTAUM VALUES (1234, '18-Aug-2016', 44, 110);
INSERT INTO TBLTESTAUM VALUES (1234, '20-Aug-2016', 45, 110);
```

Please Note :

1. the 20/Jul/2015 in first insert.
2. the Seq field may or may not have each value. It may be missing some. If you want to use it.
3. Not Nullable for Sequence is ignore able.

So rolling 13 months gives me 22/07/2015, as of today.

I want this broken down in weekly "CLASS" situations and if nothing exists for that week then the last applied CLASS. If nothing last, i.e. it is the first instance, then next applied CLASS. Till the CLASS changes.

Output to be -

```
Order Num   WeekDate    CLASS
123         27-Jul-15   459
123         3-Aug-15    459
123         10-Aug-15   459
123         17-Aug-15   459
123         24-Aug-15   459
123         31-Aug-15   459
123         7-Sep-15    459
Dates and Order Num to continue till next match in TBLTESTAUM is found
123         20-Jun-16   877
123         27-Jun-16   122
123         4-Jul-16    122
123         11-Jul-16   122
123         25-Jul-16   311
123         1-Aug-16    311
123         8-Aug-16    311
123         15-Aug-16   110
123         22-Aug-16   110
```

There are multiple order num. But I hope your code will fit one and all.
Please note

it needs to roll up to the Weekly Status.
There is a requirement to do Monthly Status. But hopefully I can figure that out from your code.

Thank you in advance.

PS: I will not be available to look at your responses for next 10hrs. Man got to sleep. But really appreciate any time you spend on this.

Comment: Also show us the expected result, and the query you've used before.

Comment: Why do you think you need a lateral join (`cross apply`)?

Comment: @jarlh I was doing piece by piece. For some reason Hyperlink formatting was wrong. And it gave me error, saying Code formatting wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Based on couple of hyperlinks I researched.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634180/oracle-sql-fill-in-missing-dates)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750336/how-to-fill-missing-dates-and-values-in-partitioned-data)

Comment: Questions... `weekdate` is always a Monday? Or is it always the same day of the week as "today's date" (if I run this on a Thursday, are all `weekdate`'s Thursdays?) Then - I did **not** notice 20/Jul/2015 in the first insert, what did you mean by that? Also, your order number in the input is 1234 but in the output it is 123 - is that a typo? Then: I see that on a Monday, the CLASS is from the week that begins that Monday, not from the prior week. That is OK and clear. What if there are two or more rows in the same week - what should be shown, the first or the last CLASS during that week?

Comment: @mathguy Yes, weekdate is always Monday. And here I may be confusing myself, let alone geniuses like you. It will be processing everyday. But will assign the Class to **Next** Monday. Lets say if the Class is 459 on 16/08/2016. And remain like that till 22/08. Then 22/08 will get that assigned. But if it changes again on 19/08 to Class 311, it will be Class 311 on the 22/08. Sorry I changed the data in Insert Statement but not in my Note. Yes, 1234 -123 is a typo.

Comment: @mathguy In regards to getting this Monthly. So the Last Class status for the previous month, i work on the W section of the code?

Comment: @seewe - yes, that should be the only part you need to touch (if you already deleted the "-6" in the outermost `select`). It will be much easier, too - just work off of `trunc(add_months(sysdate, -(level - 1), 'mm'))` - that takes you back one month at a time. No need for all those arithmetic calculations.

Comment: @mathguy thank you. I'll give it  a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below may do what you need. If it doesn't, please explain what is different compared to your requirement. (Please answer the questions I asked in my Comment to your question as well).

In this solution, I generate the needed days (first as Sundays because you want to capture what happened during the "current week", then I change them to Mondays in the final, outer query). I also generate the `order_no`'s from the table you provided, but in a meaningful real-life situation that shouldn't be necessary; you should have an "orders" table with the same order_no as the primary key, and my CTE "o" should pull order numbers from that table, not from `tbltestaum`.

Good luck!

```
with
     w ( weekdate ) as (
       select trunc(sysdate, 'iw') - 7 * (level - 1) + 6  -- This will generate Sundays
       from   dual
       connect by level <= 1 + 
                   ( trunc(sysdate, 'iw') - trunc(add_months(sysdate, -13), 'iw') ) / 7
     ), 
     o ( order_no ) as (
       select distinct order_no from tbltestaum
     ),
     prep ( order_no, dt, order_sequence, class ) as (
       select order_no, record_date, order_sequence, class
         from tbltestaum
       union all
       select order_no, weekdate, null, null
         from w cross join o
     ),
     z ( order_no, dt, order_sequence, class ) as (
       select order_no, dt, order_sequence,
              nvl( last_value(class ignore nulls) over (partition by order_no 
                                                        order by dt, order_sequence),
                  first_value(class ignore nulls) over (partition by order_no
                                                        order by dt, order_sequence
                             rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following ) )
       from   prep
     )
select order_no, to_char(dt - 6, 'dd-Mon-yy') as weekdate, class
from   z
where  order_sequence is null
;
```

Comment: This works for the requirement I said earlier. But as I said earlier, it is for the next Monday. I'm trying to change your query to fit that. Let me come back if it doesn't work. But, thank you.

Comment: OK, I will rewrite - in the hope it may help other SO members who may have the same question in the future.

Comment: Actually I don't need to re-write it. The following minor changes are needed to pick up the past week's changes on Monday morning (assuming whatever happens on a Monday is only picked up at the END of that week): delete the +6 from the third line of code, and -6 from the third line from the bottom. Then add "nulls first" after order_sequence in the "order by" portion of last_value and first_value (right before the closing parenthesis in both cases). If you want what happens on a Monday to affect that Monday, not the following one, it's even easier - delete only the +6 and -6.

Comment: Awesome that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. I hope practice will make me think like you. Genius.