# Recursive CTE to populate latest available data across many quarters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, recursive-query

here is a sample dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE UholdingsPE(
   Reference_Date DATE  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Investment     VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL
  ,Holding        VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
  ,Price          INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('3/31/2017','Example Fund 1','Apple',1);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('3/31/2017','Example Fund 1','Microsoft',1);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('6/30/2017','Example Fund 1','Apple',1);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('6/30/2017','Example Fund 1','Microsoft',1);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('9/30/2017','Example Fund 1','Apple',1);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('9/30/2017','Example Fund 1','Microsoft',1);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('12/31/2017','Example Fund 1','Apple',1);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('12/31/2017','Example Fund 1','Microsoft',1);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('6/30/2018','Example Fund 1','Apple',22);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('6/30/2018','Example Fund 1','Microsoft',22);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('12/31/2018','Example Fund 1','Apple',33);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('12/31/2018','Example Fund 1','Microsoft',33);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('6/30/2019','Example Fund 1','Apple',44);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('6/30/2019','Example Fund 1','Microsoft',44);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('12/31/2019','Example Fund 1','Apple',55);
INSERT INTO UholdingsPE(Reference_Date,Investment,Holding,Price) VALUES ('12/31/2019','Example Fund 1','Microsoft',55);
```

We receive holdings from our mutual funds quarterly. They are loaded by Reference Date, Investment, and Holding making making each row distinct. This data is put in a database in MSFT SQL Server.  Sometimes a fund does not submit their holdings for that quarter. In that case, we would like to pull in the latest available quarter's holdings (This could be 3 or 4 quarters ago) so there is no gap when performing trending analysis over multiple reference dates.

For example, say we have a fund with available SQL rows with reference dates of 3/31/19, 9/30/19 and 3/31/20 (6/30/19 and 12/31/19 are missing).  I'd like to figure out how to fill in these missing quarters with the last available quarters data.  So, 6/30/19 would be 3/31/19's data.  12/31/19 would use 9/30/19's data.  If data exists for a fund in a certain quarter though, we would just use that data.  Here is the query I am using currently, but it only goes back one quarter and fills in this quarters data with last quarters data, if the current quarters data is missing:

```
DECLARE @MaxDate Date = '20180930'  --Typically this would be the max [Reference Date] grouped by Fund as we cannot pass parameters in our BI tool

;WITH Latest_Fund
AS (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Investment ORDER BY EOMONTH([Reference Date],0) DESC) AS rn  
        FROM UholdingsPE  
        WHERE EOMONTH([Reference Date],0) >= DATEADD("MONTH",-3,@MaxDate)  
            AND EOMONTH([Reference Date],0) <= @MaxDate  
)  
SELECT
F.[Reference Date], *  
FROM DBO.UholdingsPE Z  
INNER JOIN Latest_Fund F  
    ON (Z.Investment = F.Investment or Z.Investment = F.Investment)  
        AND EOMONTH(F.[Reference Date],0) = EOMONTH(Z.[Reference Date],0)  
WHERE F.rn = 1
```

Here is an example of what I'm hoping to see:

[image: Example Data]

Here is the entire DDL for the table I am using (please note that [Current Value] is the same as price):

```
USE [EPM_Datamart]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UHoldingsPE]    Script Date: 6/30/2020 1:02:28 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UHoldingsPE](
    [Datekey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Investmentkey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Holdingskey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Primekey] [decimal](38, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Dcfkey] [decimal](38, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Cakey] [decimal](38, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Data Source] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Debt Maturity 1 Year] [float] NULL,
    [Debt Maturity 2 Years] [float] NULL,
    [Debt Maturity 3 Years] [float] NULL,
    [Debt Maturity 4 Years] [float] NULL,
    [Debt Maturity 5 Years] [float] NULL,
    [Debt Maturity After 5 Years] [float] NULL,
    [Book Value] [float] NULL,
    [Buyer] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Capital IQ ID] [int] NULL,
    [Cash] [float] NULL,
    [City] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Comments] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [Committed Capital] [float] NULL,
    [Holding Value Adjustment] [float] NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Covenant Basis] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Covenant Status] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Currency Type] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Current Cost] [float] NULL,
    [Current Value] [float] NULL,
    [Debt Ownership Percentage] [float] NULL,
    [Debt Recoursed To Fund] [float] NULL,
    [Default On Payments] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Delist Date] [date] NULL,
    [Disclosure Restrictions (If Any)] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Dividends] [float] NULL,
    [EBITDA (LTM) Acquired] [float] NULL,
    [Enterprise Value Of M&A Transactions (Net)] [float] NULL,
    [Enterprise Value] [float] NULL,
    [Exchange] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Exit IRR] [float] NULL,
    [Exit Style] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Exit Year] [int] NULL,
    [Financial Year-End] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Fixed or Floating Rate] [float] NULL,
    [Fund Undiluted Ownership] [float] NULL,
    [GP Board Seat Holders] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [GP Board Seats] [int] NULL,
    [Gross Debt] [float] NULL,
    [Gross IRR] [float] NULL,
    [Holdco Domicile] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Holding Currency] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Holding Description] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Holding Name] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Holding Type] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Holding] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Industry] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Industry Group] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Acquisition] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Book Value] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Cash] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Co-Investor Amount Invested] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Comments] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Control In Deal] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Deal Source] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Deal Type] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Debt Ownership Percentage] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Enterprise Value] [float] NULL,
    [Total Equity Value] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Gross Debt] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Investment Date] [date] NULL,
    [Initial Investment Ownership] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Investment] [float] NULL,
    [Initial LP Co-Investors?] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial LP Co-Investors] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial LTM CAPEX] [float] NULL,
    [Initial LTM EBITDA] [float] NULL,
    [Initial LTM Gross Profit] [float] NULL,
    [Initial LTM Interest Expense] [float] NULL,
    [Initial LTM Net Income] [float] NULL,
    [Initial LTM Revenue] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Main Instrument] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Management Holding Ownership] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Management Ownership] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Multiple Type] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Multiple] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Net Debt] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Number Of Employees] [int] NULL,
    [Initial Other Valuation Adjustment] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Total Equity Value] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Valuation Method] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Valuation Support Amount] [float] NULL,
    [Initial Value Driver Date] [date] NULL,
    [Initial Value Driver Type] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Initial Vehicle Ownership] [float] NULL,
    [Interests Dividends Other Income] [float] NULL,
    [Interests] [float] NULL,
    [Invested Capital] [float] NULL,
    [Investment Ownership] [float] NULL,
    [Investment Status] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Investment] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [IPO Date] [date] NULL,
    [IPO Share Price] [float] NULL,
    [Last Realization Date] [date] NULL,
    [Last Updated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Last Valuation Date] [date] NULL,
    [Line Of Credit Outstanding?] [float] NULL,
    [Lock-Up Period End Date] [date] NULL,
    [LTM CAPEX] [float] NULL,
    [LTM EBITDA] [float] NULL,
    [LTM Gross Profit] [float] NULL,
    [LTM Interest Expense] [float] NULL,
    [LTM Net Income] [float] NULL,
    [LTM Revenue] [float] NULL,
    [M&A Activity Notes] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Main Instrument] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Management Holding Ownership] [float] NULL,
    [Management Ownership] [float] NULL,
    [Max Multiple] [float] NULL,
    [Method Of Exit] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Min Multiple] [float] NULL,
    [Multiple Type] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Multiple] [float] NULL,
    [Net Debt] [float] NULL,
    [Number Of Employees] [int] NULL,
    [Number Of M&A Transactions (Net)] [float] NULL,
    [Number Of Shares] [float] NULL,
    [Operating Data Date 1] [date] NULL,
    [Operating Data Date 2] [date] NULL,
    [Operating Data Date 3] [date] NULL,
    [Operating Data Type 1] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Operating Data Type 2] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Operating Data Type 3] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Other Income] [float] NULL,
    [Period End Date For LTM] [date] NULL,
    [PIK Toggle] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Position Comments] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Primary Market (Region)] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Realized Gains/Losses] [float] NULL,
    [Realized Proceeds] [float] NULL,
    [Reference Date] [date] NULL,
    [Return Of Cost] [float] NULL,
    [Revenue (LTM) Acquired] [float] NULL,
    [Sector] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Seller] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Strategy] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Sub-Industry] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Ticker] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Total # Of Board Members] [int] NULL,
    [Total Invested (LP Co-Investors)] [float] NULL,
    [Total Investment Value] [float] NULL,
    [Transaction Co-Leads] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Transaction Costs] [float] NULL,
    [Transaction Lead] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [TTM EBITDA 2] [float] NULL,
    [TTM EBITDA 3] [float] NULL,
    [TTM Revenue 2] [float] NULL,
    [TTM Revenue 3] [float] NULL,
    [Valuation Comments] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Valuation Method] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Value Driver Amount] [float] NULL,
    [Value Driver Date] [date] NULL,
    [Value Driver Type] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Vehicle Ownership At Exit] [float] NULL,
    [Vehicle Ownership] [float] NULL,
    [Website] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Asset Class] [varchar](1000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving last record in each group from database - SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4751913/2029983)

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, my apologies, I've attached a link to sample data.  I'm unable to send actual data due to the sensitive nature of finance data.  Please keep in mind that the actual data has about 30 columns.  I've included those of importance here.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, Thank you for replying.  That option appears to only pull the last quarter (1 row), instead of filling in the missing quarters with the latest available quarter.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Pictures of data without data types doesn't help us help you.

Comment: *"hat option appears to only pull the last quarter (1 row)"* which is what I read as what you are after. If that isn't the case, then you need to provide that sample data and expected results you were asked for.

Comment: Perhaps what you are actually after is a calendar table?

Comment: Hi all, sorry, this is only my second posting.  Thank you for your help.  @HABO, I've added a script to create an example table.  I could potentially join this data to a calendar table to help with the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, what I'm looking for is very similar to the question you answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750336/how-to-fill-missing-dates-and-values-in-partitioned-data.  This person wanted to go back in time and fill in data.  I want to go forward and use the prior quarters data for my next quarter (if the quarter is missing for that fund)

Comment: The cursor option from @AndreiOdegov solved my problems!  Thank you all again for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to get from the `UholdingsPE` table all combinations of all quarters between the minimum and maximum values ​​of the `Reference_Date` column and all the different values ​​of the `Investment` and `Holding` columns. All the rows are returned from the `cih` CTE. After that, you need to extract the value of the `Price` column of the row of the `UholdingsPE` table that is the closest by of the value of the `Reference_Date` column to the value of the `Reference_Date` column of the current row of the `cih` CTE.

```
with
  cc as (
    select
      min(Reference_Date) as Reference_Date,
      max(Reference_Date) as xq
    from UholdingsPE
    union all
    select eomonth(dateadd(qq, 1, q)), xq
    from cc
    where q < xq
  ),
  ii as (select distinct Investment from UholdingsPE),
  hh as (select distinct Holding from UholdingsPE),
  cih as (
    select Reference_Date, Investment, Holding
    from cc
    cross join ii
    cross join hh
  )
select *
from cih
cross apply (
  select a.Price
  from UholdingsPE as a
  where
    a.Reference_Date <= cih.Reference_Date and
    a.Investment = cih.Investment and
    a.Holding = cih.Holding
  order by a.Reference_Date desc
    offset 0 rows
    fetch first 1 row only
) as ca
order by Reference_Date, Investment, Holding
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
|    |    Reference_Date   |   Investment   |  Holding  | Price |
+----+---------------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | 31.03.2017 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |     1 |
|  2 | 31.03.2017 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |     1 |
|  3 | 30.06.2017 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |     1 |
|  4 | 30.06.2017 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |     1 |
|  5 | 30.09.2017 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |     1 |
|  6 | 30.09.2017 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |     1 |
|  7 | 31.12.2017 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |     1 |
|  8 | 31.12.2017 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |     1 |
|  9 | 31.03.2018 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |     1 |
| 10 | 31.03.2018 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |     1 |
| 11 | 30.06.2018 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |    22 |
| 12 | 30.06.2018 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |    22 |
| 13 | 30.09.2018 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |    22 |
| 14 | 30.09.2018 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |    22 |
| 15 | 31.12.2018 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |    33 |
| 16 | 31.12.2018 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |    33 |
| 17 | 31.03.2019 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |    33 |
| 18 | 31.03.2019 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |    33 |
| 19 | 30.06.2019 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |    44 |
| 20 | 30.06.2019 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |    44 |
| 21 | 30.09.2019 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |    44 |
| 22 | 30.09.2019 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |    44 |
| 23 | 31.12.2019 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Apple     |    55 |
| 24 | 31.12.2019 00:00:00 | Example Fund 1 | Microsoft |    55 |
+----+---------------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/edit/VMEUX1564).

Let's try the cursor-based solution.

```
declare
  @prev_inv varchar(14), @Investment varchar(14),
  @prev_hold varchar(9), @Holding varchar(9),
  @prev_ref_date date, @Reference_date date,
  @prev_price integer, @Price integer, @qdiff integer;
declare
  c cursor forward_only static read_only for
    select Investment, Holding, Reference_Date, Price from UholdingsPE
    union all
    select Investment, Holding, ref_date, -1
    from (select max(Reference_Date) as ref_date from UholdingsPE) as a
    cross join (select distinct Investment from UholdingsPE) as b
    cross join (select distinct Holding from UholdingsPE) as c
    order by Investment, Holding, Reference_Date, Price desc;
open c;
fetch next from c into @Investment, @Holding, @Reference_Date, @Price;
select
  @prev_inv = @Investment,
  @prev_hold = @Holding,
  @prev_ref_date = @Reference_date,
  @prev_price = @Price;
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
  fetch next from c into @Investment, @Holding, @Reference_Date, @Price;
  set @qdiff = datediff(q, @prev_ref_date, @Reference_date);
  if @prev_inv = @Investment and
     @prev_hold = @Holding and
     @qdiff > 1
  begin
    insert into miss_UholdingsPE(Investment,
                                 Holding,
                                 Price,
                                 Reference_Date)
      select
        @prev_inv, @prev_hold, @prev_price,
        eomonth(dateadd(q, nums.n, @prev_ref_date))
      from nums
      where nums.n < @qdiff + iif(@Price = -1, 1, 0);
  end;
  select
    @prev_inv = @Investment,
    @prev_hold = @Holding,
    @prev_ref_date = @Reference_date,
    @prev_price = @Price;
end;
close c;
deallocate c;
```

[Cursor-based solution demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a775cd/4).

Another set-based solution:

```
with
  a as (select distinct Investment, Holding from stage_UholdingsPE),
  b as (
    select Q.Reference_Date, a.Investment, a.Holding
    from a
    cross join (
      select eomonth(dateadd(quarter, n, '20160331'))
      from Nums(0, datediff(quarter, '20160331', '20191231'))
    ) as Q(Reference_Date)
    where not exists(select * from stage_UholdingsPE as s
                     where
                       s.Reference_Date = Q.Reference_Date and
                       s.Investment = a.Investment and
                       s.Holding = a.Holding)
  )
insert into stage_UholdingsPE(Reference_Date, Investment, Holding, Price)
  select Reference_Date, Investment, Holding, null from b;
go
with
  a as (
    select
      *,
      count(Price) over(partition by Investment, Holding
                        order by Reference_Date
                        rows unbounded preceding) as c
    from stage_UholdingsPE
  )
insert into full_UholdingsPE(Reference_Date, Investment, Holding, Price)
  select
    Reference_Date, Investment, Holding,
    max(Price) over(partition by c) as Price
  from a;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e49b2/1).

Comment: Hi @AndreOdegov, Thank you so much for the help.  When I run your query on our actual data (not a large dataset - 122,000 rows), the query runs for 45 min (then I kill it).  Currently, I'm only using the "Price" column, but would eventually add 40 more columns in this query.  Can you help?

Comment: But, that being said, your example output is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Check the cursor-based solution.

Comment: I think this is working!  I've had to make a few tweaks.  Be back tomorrow.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm working on adding the additional columns to your script.  Do I need to add every column and variable to your cursor as well?

Comment: I see that you've set price = -1.  Would I need to do this for the other 40 columns?

Comment: @JeffS, can you show the DDL of the `UholdingsPE` table? Also check out the new solution, which processes ~ 180,000 rows. [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e49b2/1) to this solution.

Comment: Hi @AndreiOdegov, please see the updated post above.  Current Value is the same as Price used in the above example.  I should've just said Current Value originally.  In this DDL, Reference Date, Holding and Investment are nullable.  I think that would need to change based on your example (I think this is an error on mypart).

Comment: Which columns should be used in the `partition` clause? Which columns should be used in the `order by` clause? Which columns are missing values? Is the set of these columns unchanged for each missing row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216975/discussion-between-jeff-s-and-andrei-odegov).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
DECLARE @MaxDate Date = '20191231'  --Typically this would be the max Reference_Date grouped by Fund as we cannot pass parameters in our BI tool

declare @quarter_end_date date = (select min(Reference_Date) from UholdingsPE)
declare @start_date date = @quarter_end_date

declare cur cursor fast_forward for select distinct Investment, Holding from UholdingsPE

declare @Investment varchar(100), @Holding varchar(10)
declare @latest_holdings int

open cur
fetch next from cur into @Investment, @Holding
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    while (@quarter_end_date <= convert(date, @MaxDate))
    begin
        if ((select count(1) from UholdingsPE where Reference_Date = @quarter_end_date and Investment = @Investment and Holding = @Holding) = 0)
        begin
            set @latest_holdings = (select top 1 Price from UholdingsPE where Reference_Date <= @quarter_end_date and Investment = @Investment and Holding = @Holding order by Reference_Date desc)
            insert into UholdingsPE select @quarter_end_date, @Investment, @Holding, @latest_holdings
        end
        set @quarter_end_date = eomonth(dateadd(mm, 3, @quarter_end_date))
    end
    set @quarter_end_date = eomonth(dateadd(mm, 3, @start_date))
    fetch next from cur into @Investment, @Holding
end
close cur
deallocate cur

select * from UholdingsPE
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5829add1f942afe6b8dacfc74a1b2422)**.

Comment: Hi @sacse, Thank you so much for the help.  When I run your query on our actual data (not a large dataset - 122,000 rows), the query runs for 45 min (then I kill it).  Currently, I'm only using the "Price" column, but would eventually add 40 more columns in this query.  Can you help?

Comment: But, that being said, your example output is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @JeffS how many distinct values are there in your table for Investment, Holding?

Comment: @JeffS try [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff777654873154636e2fce04f1dffed2) new approach.

Comment: Hi @sacse.  There are 246 distinct rows for Investment.  There are 5,560 distinct rows for Holding.  There are 13 distinct Reference Dates.  There are 6,461 distinct rows for the combination of investment and holding.

Comment: @JeffS thanks! did you try the new approach given in the previous comment?

Comment: Hi @sacse, thank you again for the help.  The query takes quite a bit of time to run.  I kill it at 10 minutes.  I'm worried that adding the other 40 columns (price is only one column) would make it unusable.