# How to fill missing dates in BigQuery?

Tags: python, date, datetime, google-bigquery

This question is related to [How to fill missing dates and values in partitioned data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750336/how-to-fill-missing-dates-and-values-in-partitioned-data), but since the solution doesn't work for BigQuery, I'm posting the question again.

I have the following hypothetical table:

```
name       date          val
-------------------------------
A          01/01/2020     1.5
A          01/03/2020     2
A          01/06/2020     5
B          01/02/2020     90
B          01/07/2020     10
```

I want to fill in the dates in between the gaps and copy over the value from the most recent following date. In addition, I would like to fill in dates that 1) go back to a pre-set MINDATE (let's say it's 12/29/2019) and 2) go up to the current date (let's say it's 01/09/2020) - and for 2) the default values will be 1.

So, the output would be:

```
name       date          val
-------------------------------
A          12/29/2019     1.5
A          12/30/2019     1.5
A          12/31/2019     1.5
A          01/01/2020     1.5   <- original
A          01/02/2020     2
A          01/03/2020     2     <- original
A          01/04/2020     5
A          01/05/2020     5
A          01/06/2020     5     <- original
A          01/07/2020     1
A          01/08/2020     1
A          01/09/2020     1
B          12/29/2019     90
B          12/30/2019     90
B          12/31/2019     90
B          01/01/2020     90
B          01/02/2020     90    <- original
B          01/03/2020     10
B          01/04/2020     10
B          01/05/2020     10
B          01/06/2020     10
B          01/07/2020     10    <- original
B          01/08/2020     1
B          01/09/2020     1
```

The accepted [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750374/6653295) in the above question doesn't work in BigQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work

```
with base as (

select 'A' as name,           '01/01/2020' as date,     1.5 as val  union all
select 'A' as name,           '01/03/2020' as date,     2 as val union all
select 'A' as name,           '01/06/2020' as date,     5 as val union all
select 'B' as name,           '01/02/2020' as date,     90 as val union all
select 'B' as name,           '01/07/2020' as date,     10 as val
),

missing_dates as (

select name,dates as date from 
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2019-12-29', '2020-01-09', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS dates cross join (select distinct name from base)

), joined as (
select distinct missing_dates.name, missing_dates.date,val 
from  missing_dates 
left join base on missing_dates.name = base.name 
and  parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', base.date) = missing_dates.date

)

select * except(val), 
ifnull(first_value(val ignore nulls) over(partition by name order by date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND
    UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),1) as va1 
from joined
```