# How to fill missing dates in BigQuery by partition (no backfill)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Related to [How to fill missing dates in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66983100/how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-bigquery), but without back filling/forward filling:

Suppose I have the following sales data:

```
order_date      product         store           sales
_______________________________________________________
2021-05-01      1               1               10
2021-05-04      1               1               5

2021-04-25      1               2               3
2021-04-30      1               2               9
2021-05-10      1               2               1

2021-05-02      2               1               3
2021-05-04      2               1               3
```

and my desired output is to fill empty dates w/ 0, but partitioned on `product` and `store` (and not to back fill to a global `MIN(DATE)` or forward fill to a global `MAX(DATE)`:

```
order_date      product         store           sales
_______________________________________________________
2021-05-01      1               1               10
2021-05-02      1               1               0
2021-05-03      1               1               0
2021-05-04      1               1               5

2021-04-25      1               2               3
2021-04-26      1               2               0
...             ...             ...             ... (all 0s)
2021-04-29      1               2               0
2021-04-30      1               2               9
...             ...             ...             ... (all 0s)
2021-05-10      1               2               1

2021-05-02      2               1               3
2021-05-03      2               1               0
2021-05-04      2               1               3
```

How would I accomplish this (specifically in BigQuery)?

My initial thought is that I may need to create a table like

```
SELECT 
    product, store,
    MIN(order_date) min_date,
    MAX(order_date) max_date
FROM mydata
GROUP BY product, store
```

but I'm not sure how I'd use that to partition the original `mydata` table and fill dates between with `IFNULL(sales,0) sales`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure what the ask is! you might want to provide more details

Comment: The desired output is a similar table, but for any particular `store`/`product` pair, fill in empty dates with 0 for `sales`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select order_date, product, store, ifnull(sales, 0) sales 
from (
  select product, store, order_date 
  from (
    select product, store, min(order_date) start_date, max(order_date) end_date
    from `project.dataset.table`
    group by product, store
  ), unnest(generate_date_array(start_date, end_date)) order_date
)
left join `project.dataset.table` 
using(product, store, order_date)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: This is right what I was looking for. Than you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate all the rows.  Then use `left join` to bring in the existing data:

```
select order_date, sp.product, sp.store,
       coalesce(sales, 0) as sales
from (select distinct store, product from t) sp cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(date '2021-04-01', date '2021-05-31', interval 1 day) day left join
     t
     on sp.store = t.store and sp.product = t.product and
        day = sp.order_date;
```

The above generates the data for all days in April and May.  You can adjust the time period.

Comment: The cross join is agnostic of `store`/`product` and would backfill/forward fill 0s for time periods that aren't relevant to that pair.